# Many CLLocationManager instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, geolocation, cllocationmanager

If I init additional CLLocaitonManager instance that track user location, is It will increase the load? Or Should I using one CLLocaitonManager instance between classes?

Comment: can you plz elobrate your question?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614511/is-there-any-performance-penalty-for-using-multiple-cllocationmanager-instances/3614556#3614556

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Creating too many `CLLocationManager` or increasing the update intervals of the Core location services severely drains battery. So creating too many instances is not advised. Dont see a need for this.

A good practice is to init one `CLLocationManager` in a viewController. If moving to another viewController, then stopUpdates on the current `CLLocationManager` & create a new manager in the new viewController. This is one pattern.

Another pattern is to create a `CLLocationManager` in app delegate & make it available throughout your app. This is like a global variable. But generally avoid global declaration of this variable because it continuously consumes your battery life.

So basically if all your classes are part of only one viewController then create only one `CLLocationManager` & share the location updates. If not then create one for each viewController.

Comment: Do you have any evidence of this? I've always made a singleton with a CLLocationManager but as I do it I'm always struck by how Apple designer the API assuming you would have multiple CLLocation managers. (e.g. didUpdateToLocation specifies a CLLocationManager)

Answer (score 0):

Location services require the presence of specific hardware on the given device. So thats why ,its doesn't matter how many instance of CLLocationManager are created. Generally avoid global declaration of this variable because it continuously consumes your battery life. Another wise stop and start each time when ever you need to finding user location.